# Lint SCSS/SASS in single file components Vue.js in PhpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, lint, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js with a single file component approach. My IDE is PhpStorm and I would like to find a way so that the SCSS contained in the `<style></style>` inside a `.vue` file is well recognized.

Currently it looks like the picture I attached -- I don't know whether it is a plugin to install or a setting to change in PhpStorm.

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'Tree',
        components: {

        },

    }
</script>
<style lang="scss">
   ... My SASS / SCSS / CSS
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself :

You need to add `rel="stylesheet/scss"` so it looks like

```
<style lang="sass" rel="stylesheet/scss"></style>
```

OR

```
 <style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss"></style>
```

Answer (score 6):

I found your solution not to be helpful. using `type="text/scss"` seemed to fix it for me though if anyone else has trouble.

Comment: Yeah, `type="text/scss"` does the job. This should be the correct answer. The previous 
 one `rel="stylesheet/scss"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case both didn't work.

Try using the following for a fix.

`<style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/scss">`